# How can OpenID Connect utilize userinfo for authorization?

Tags: openid-connect, remote-validation, mod-auth-openidc

I'm utilizing [mod_auth_openidc](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc) to front an API that has neither authentication nor authorization. The same endpoint also serves UI, so it has interactive and server-to-server queries hitting it. This is something the module has `AuthType auth-openidc` for. So the module acts as Resource Server in OAuth2.

When configuring this, I realized I accept access tokens from a password grant, so all my users have roles assigned to them and we don't really use scopes on the client ids. So, naturally, I want to restrict access to the endpoint via role like this:

```
<Location />
  AuthType auth-openidc
  OIDCOAuthIntrospectionEndpoint https://localhost/oauth2/introspect
  OIDCOAuthRemoteUserClaim sub
  OIDCOAuthClientID 1111
  OIDCOAuthClientSecret 2222
  Require claim roles:MYAPI_ACCESS
</Location>
```

The validation endpoint is a stock [RFC 7662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) compliant box and the config is basically textbook [example](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Resource-Server#rfc-7662-based-oauth-20-token-introspection).

My twist is the `Require` authz. When using OAuth2 remote validation, openid-connect doesn't seem to look up the user info for the remote user, it just copies all attributes it gets from the `/introspect` endpoint and tries to match the Require against it.

My **question** is: how can I make openid-connect lookup the corresponding user info (via a call to an existing `/userinfo` endpoint) once it has the remote user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make the module call the user info endpoint when acting as a OAuth 2.0 Resource Server. What you can do is map the relevant claims to the access token in your Provider.